# Reffering the IP of an EC2 Instance to a Inbound Rule Using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm new to Terraform.

I'm trying to create a Security Group that within it's Inbounds Rules one of then grant access to the Bastion Host (located at a public subnet) to Access the NGINX server (located at a private subnet).

**Objective:** So I can SSH from my machine to the Bastion and then from the Bastion to the NGINX Server

I don't know what method to use, because technically the IP of the Bastion Host will be "created" after I do the Terraform Init.

I was thinking I could user Variables, but honestly I don't know how, do you think I would have to grant an Static IP for the Bastion? So I could "write" the IP at the ingress part of the Security Group HCL code?

**I've made some comments on the code below. I hope it helps to understand my question.**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "public_sg" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc_server_nginx.id

  ingress { # SSH from my machine Inbound Rule
    protocol  = "tcp"
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["187.74.121.76/32"]
  }

  ingress { # SSH from Bastion to NGINX Server Inbound Rule
    protocol  = "tcp"
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    cidr_blocks = [] # How to refer the IP of the Bastion Host?
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Security Group Name"
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use separate security groups for the Nginx server and the Bastion server. Then in the Nginx server's security group, allow access from the Bastion host's security group by specifying the security group ID instead of an IP address in the security group rule.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it worked flawlessly!!! Thank you very much! I'm still can't give upvotes because my user is new. Sorry.

Comment: @rbmxrenato please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was not aware of that.